# Problems accessing stylesheets/scripts loaded in WP header

Tags: headers

When I view my pages source code I get the following:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='css_bootstrap-css'  href='http://*******.com/wp-content/themes/synapse/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css?ver=3.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

And when I click on the link:

```
http://*******.com/wp-content/themes/synapse/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css?ver=3.5
```

It won't work and this is shown:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
    <p>You don't have permission to access /domains/*******.com/wp-content/themes/synapse/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
    on this server.</p>
    </body></html>
```

It's the same for the all the others scripts/stylesheets.

Why is that?

Comment: Is that a script loaded by a plugin? or is it defined in your header.php? If its in your header, have you tried href="<?php echo(get_stylesheet_directory_uri());?>js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"

Answer (score 2):

Opps had same issue few weeks back.
check your .htaccess file some code written to block css file that is why you are getting 403 error message. code can be look like

```
<Files ~ "(.js|.css)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: I agree with Manish, it's most likely a permission problem like his example.  Also check permissions on the folder where the stylesheet(s) reside that it has "read" permissions for the public user.